# Using x-www-from-urlencoded content-type returns wrong int

Tags: php

I have such problem:

Here is one file:

test_info.php

```
<?php

var_dump(strlen(file_get_contents('php://input')),
  $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']);

?>
```

Here is POST'ing file:

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/test_info.php', false, stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => str_repeat('a', 1024*1024*2), 'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'))));

?>
```

When i use content-type x-www-form-urlencoded i get such results from var_dump:

int(1044736)
string(7) "2097152"

If i put \n character in 'Content-type: \n', then it returns correct results:

int(2097152)
string(7) "2097152"

If i change content-type to multipart/form-data it returns correct results too.
int(2097152)

p.s. on other server i get it correctly too, without modifying content-type.

Maybe someone got a clue why is it returning wrong it? (cutting content)

thanks

Comment: How is content that’s just a long `aaaaaaaa…` string `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: yes, it is just a string with specific length.

Comment: I found a problem, it was apache security module problem. solved.